# How do register numbers affect number of loads and stores in ISA?

Tags: load, store, cpu-registers, instruction-set

I am trying to solve a question about register numbers in instruction set architecture. The question is;

> Suppose that the code sequence is to compute A=B+C, B=A+C, and D=A-B. Assume that all of A, B, C, and D are initially in memory. List the sequence of instructions for Register (load-store) ISA, and compare the number of loads and stores that you need in order to do the computation when:
>   (a) There are 2 architecture registers.
>   (b) There are 3 architecture registers.

I've got this answer for (a);

```
Load R1,B
Load R2,C
Add R1,R1,R2
Store R1,A
Add R2,R1,R2
Store R2,B
Sub R1,R1,R2
Store R1,D
```

And I've got this answer for (b);

```
Load R1,B
Load R2,C
Add R3,R1,R2
Store R3,A
Add R1,R2,R3
Store R1,B
Sub R2,R3,R1
Store R2,D
```

So, I am having same loads and stores numbers for both computation. Am I doing something wrong? or Is my answer correct?

Comment: I hate to say it, but it definitely looks like, for this particular set of equations, a) is "optimal" and b) - despite having more registers available - involves exactly the same work.  To me, it looks like your answer is "correct".